# Какие метрики архитектуры ухудшает/улучшает рефакторинг с упором на SOLID + DRY + IoC?

Tags: ооп

Какие метрики архитектуры ухудшает/улучшает рефакторинг с упором на SOLID + DRY + IoC?

Comment: С хабра вопрос взяли?)

Comment: Да:)
Очень интересно стало, как на него хотя бы примерно ответить)

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, а относительно только допустим IoC можно ответить на такой вопрос? Если да, ответьте, пожалуйста

Comment: Чувствую свою ущербность...

Answer (score 2):

Ответы на эти вопросы можно найти в книге:

"Быстрая разработка программ."
Роберт Мартин. 
Он их кстати и придумал.

А вообще архитектура изначально должна рассчитываться на минимальную зависимость модулей между собой, тогда принципы SOLID будут работать. Это также даст реальную "физическую" модульность проекта и снизит дополнительные издержки компиляции, которые тратятся на выяснение зависимостей модулей, а не на построение исходного кода.
То есть когда крупный многомодульный проект собирается очень долго, то чаще всего причина этого не в компиляции .cpp модуля, а в неправильной организации заголовков .h. Чтобы этого избежать проект должен соответствовать принципам SOLID, которые минимизируют количество ссылок классов между собой, и ведут к минимальной зависимости классов при исправлении(рефакторинге)

DRY + loc это просто очень закрученный подвид абстракции. Только вместо формирования обобщенных классов и функций, предполагается всё это прятать как отдельный модуль.

Comment: Интересно, разве не настораживает наличие в этом абзаце множества С++-ных аспектов?

З.Ы. Если следовать этой логике, то ничего кроме low coupling и high cohesion, вообще ничего не нужно (хотя, впрочем, это верно).